# Google Sheets Range.CopyTo failing to read "to" range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Trying to do a basic copy of non-adjacent columns into adjacent columns based on offsets from the active cell (which contains the date for the data below), and it isn't recognising the offset moves for either paste.  I've simplified it right down to this:

```
function CopyCols() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var headerCell = spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
  var col1 = headerCell.offset(0,1)
  spreadsheet.getRange('I2:I222').copyTo(col1, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var col2 = col1.offset(1,0)
  spreadsheet.getRange('K2:K222').copyTo(col2, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

and all that happens is that it pastes everything based on the top-left of the `headerCell` range (i.e. the current active cell) and not the offset values.

Comment: Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I thought it so trivial I didn't bother, but you are right, I should have done.  Especially as in preparing some I found out what the first issue was - I was starting from a merged cell, which although I was pasting using vars which were offset from there, it threw an error because of it (got to be a bug I should file).  The error didn't show on my live sheet. Second issue was I'd reversed my rows/cols due to coding in parallel on 2 platforms with different APIs.  Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code behaves similarly to this:

| A | B | C | ... | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| active cell |  |  |  | 1 |  | 3 |
|  |  |  |  | 2 |  | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

to:

| A | B | C | ... | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| active cell | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |

I'm assuming you want to go from this:

| A | B | C | ... | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| active cell |  |  |  | 1 |  | 3 |
|  |  |  |  | 2 |  | 4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

To this:

| A | B | C | ... | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| active cell | 1 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
|  | 2 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

In which case, you'd need to update this line to:

```
var col2 = col1.offset(0,1)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'd just been coding coords on a diff platform using (x,y) not, as here effectively is, (y,x) and had just carried on doing the same.  You deserve the rep points for pointing out my blind stupidity! :)   There was also a problem with using offsets and a merged cell as per my response above.